# Java Use Variable Name to Manipulate Array

Tags: java

Is it possible to use a variable name to manipulate an array?

For example:

```
String addto = "database";
database = new String[2];
```

I want to add values into the array named "database", which has only 1 column.

Would it be possible to do something like...

```
addto[0] = hi;
addto[1] = hi1;
```

instead of

```
database[0] = hi;
database[1] = hi1;
```

etc? Use the value inside "addto" ("database") to manipulate the array?

Thanks!

**edit: changed String addto to "database" (with "")**

Comment: Is the array name, e.g., `database`, coming from user input, or what?

Comment: Yes it is coming from user input

Comment: You may look for reflections http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayInstance.html and http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Comment: How many arrays do you have?  Could you manually add them to a `Map<string, object[]>`, for instance, to link a name to the actual array?

Comment: The first line of code in your question will not compile because `database` is an array.

Comment: @Hassan sorry I meant String addto = "database";

Comment: Okay then the rest of the code won't compile.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have the name of your array variable, but not a reference to it. Is that even possible? Where is the `database` array initialized?

Comment: Your'e accessing `addto` and `database` as arrays, while they are just `String`s.

Comment: @Hassan database is an array, as indicated in the question

Comment: What's the purpose of this? If you have the database reference, why go through the trouble of trying to indirectly reference it?

Comment: Okay why don't you just do `String[] addto = database`? Is that what you want to do?

Comment: But as @Thor84no says, what is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd want to use something like:

```
Map<String, String[]> arrays = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
arrays.put("database", new String[2]);

...

map.get(addTo)[0] = hi;
map.get(addTo)[1] = hi1;
```

Comment: does this create a new array named "database"?

Comment: @01jayss: No, objects don't have names. It creates a new array, and make that the value associated with the key "database" in a map.

Answer (score 0):

```
String addto = "database"; 
database = new String[2];  
addto[0] = hi;  
addto[1] = hi1;
```

This code will not compile because `addto` is a String and does not support indexing with `[]`. To do something similar to this, you can use a [`java.util.Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) as illustrated by Jon Skeet.